# FileNotFoundError while copying file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I work on Ubuntu 18.04 with python 3.8, and I have an intermittent exception with `shutil.copy2` function:

```
def copy_file(src, dst):
    assert os.path.exists(src), "Source file does not exist"
    assert os.path.exists(dst), "Destination folder does not exist"
    shutil.copy2(src, dst)
```

Randomly, this function, for the same file/folder raises a `FileNotFoundError` exception in `shutil.copystat` subfunction. I tried to direclty use `shutil.copyfile` but here again the copied file is randomly inexistent. Adding some `sleep` does not help either.

In the `shutil.copystat`, the exception is raised when the function tries to access the file to get its metadata

```
[L372] lookup("utime")(dst, ns=(st.st_atime_ns, st.st_mtime_ns),
           follow_symlinks=follow)
```

as stated:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
../../miniconda3/envs/test_env/lib/python3.8/shutil.py:372: FileNotFoundError
```

Comment: My first thought is the file actually does not exist -- possibly some sort of race condition that causes the file to be deleted after your assert.. Try putting the `shutil.copy2()` call in `try/except` block, and in the exception handler, do `print(os.listdir(os.dirname(src))`

Comment: the exception is raised because the file does not exist in the destination folder, it is not raised because of the source file